# Bash: autocompletion in nested command

Tags: bash, osx, autocomplete

I am using bash and what I'm trying to do is achieve autocompletion in a nested command. For example, typing:

```
kill $(cat tmp/p|
```

followed by `<tab>` would yield

```
kill $(cat tmp/pids/
```

And I'd like to type `s<tab>)`to get to

```
kill $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)
```

Unfortunately, my bash autocompletion is not working in this particular situation.

Is there a way to fix this?

Here's my bash version:

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using the completion settings from `bash-completion`. Tab completion in command substitution does not work with that. It does work without those, using the default settings, though. Comment out wherever you have sourced `/usr/local/etc/bash_completion` (assuming default homebrew, given the version string), start a new shell and try again.

Comment: Indeed I'm using `bash-completion@2` from brew. I just tested a bash instance without those lines and I confirm it's working correctly. Is there a way to keep the `bash-completion@2` functionality while still having path completion working in nested commands?

Comment: @nerfologist Try pressing Esc-/ instead of tab. According to [the bash-completion FAQ](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion#faq), using `M-/` (Meta+`/`, Meta is Esc by default, IIRC) bypasses bash-completion.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to read PID from file and kill the process:

```
pkill -F /path/to/file
```

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work in the version of `pkill` that's available from brew at this time.